# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This is my code

```
sqlquery = "select * from Mytables where cname='" + name + "' and cast(cast('" + txtselectdate.Text + "' as char(8)) as datetime)";
```

Getting error as Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Please suggest some ideas

Comment: What is the value for `txtselectdate.Text`?

Comment: txtselectdate.Text = dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: So you want to convert `dd/MM/yyyy` to a date, or did you want `31/12/2014` to convert to a date?

Comment: I am getting error as Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime so i tried to use the above convertion but still I didnt get the solution

Comment: Do yourself a BIG favor and stop executing values especially those that are direct user input. You need to parameterize your queries. As posted this is a textbook sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai all thanks for the help I got the answer it was a datatype problem in my database

I havent saved the data type as datetime so they occurs a clash in updating previously it was nvarchar

Answer (score 1):

Use tihs

```
CONVERT(Datetime,txtselectdate.Text,110)
```

You can use any format instead of 110

or

you can simply pass the converted date in your query like this

```
  DateTime.Parse(txtselectdate.Text)
```

then you do not need to cast it in query.

===========Update ========

```
select * from mytable where cname='" + name + "' and yourcolumnname=CONVERT(Datetime,'" + txtselectdate.Text + "',110)"
```

Add column name in your query by which this textbox value will match.

Comment: getting error as "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'."

Comment: sqlquery = "select * from mytable where cname='" + name + "' and CONVERT(Datetime,'" + txtselectdate.Text + "',110)";

Comment: Have you changed the query as i have written in the answer ?

Comment: Hai all thanks for the help I got the answer it was a datatype problem in my database